# Optimal way to find last call attempt - CTI database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm using a MSSQL database as backend for small CTI application and I'm wondering if there is a better way to query last call attemp for each client called in CTI database.

I got two tables CUSTOMERS and CALLS.  CALLS store a history of all calls with foreign key - CUSTOMER_ID as link to CUSTOMER table).

My query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM CALLS x 
JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(CALL_ID), CUSTOMER_ID FROM CALLS GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) y 
ON 
x.CALL_ID = y.CALL_ID
```

With couple tousands of records in calls tables and couple other joins it's getting to take a bit too much time. I would be grateful for some ideas how to speed it up.

Shag

Comment: We would need to see the table definitions, including and key and indexes to correctly answer this question.  Also the rowcounts of the tables would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `window function` which will avoid hitting the same tables twice

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY CALL_ID DESC) rn,
              *
       FROM   CALLS) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```